# Text extracted by pdfbox contains weird question mark symbols in place of spaces

Tags: java, pdfbox

When I tried to extract text from PDF using Apache PDFBox 2.0.18, the output looked like below,

[image]

How can I avoid those question mark symbols ?
Below is my pdf extraction method.

```
 public static String getPDFContent(File pdfFile) throws IOException {
    PDDocument doc = null;
    String text = null;
    try {
        doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
        text = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("An exception occurred while extracting text from pdf using Apache PDFBox.");
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        if( doc != null )
        {
            doc.close();
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Please share the PDF in question. Furthermore, *how* do you output the string and get those symbols?

Comment: Please read the FAQ on text extraction: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#text-extraction

Comment: That link is utterly unhelpful